# How to clean up memory usage of a database after a big sql query

Tags: sql-server-2016

I made a select query which returned about 20 million rows.
Memory usage jumped from 300MB to 3.x GB.

How can I release the additional memory for this database after the query is done, without restarting the SQL process?

[image]

---

[image]

I tried:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
Declare @dbid int = db_ID() 
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (22)
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('Comments')
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
```

But it only decreases memory usage by 300MB.

Comment: Why do you think this is needed?

Comment: Because I want to free memory, I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Just let your system manage its memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/paul-white) wrote a response to the question [What's a good way to get SQL Server to release memory to the operating system on a dev machine?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115270/whats-a-good-way-to-get-sql-server-to-release-memory-to-the-operating-system-on).  This approach **IS** at the instance level, but that may be acceptable for your situation.

Quoting Paul:

> I routinely increase and decrease the max server memory configuration
>   option for the SQL Server 2005-2016 instances running on my laptop
>   (with lock pages in memory enabled). Has never caused me any problems,
>   and memory always seems to be released quickly.

With that in mind and referencing [Server Memory Server Configuration Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options), it would *seem* that you could simply invoke the following T-SQL once to reduce the memory and then again to increase the memory by modifying the max memory value:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: Or via [SSMS GUI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Before I set  max server memory to 16 MB. Now I have a problem accessing my SQL Instance. EventViewer tells me: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
How can I increase the max memory now again without access via SSMS?
When I start the service under Services, it starts, but shuts down quickly afterwards.

Comment: Can you put your T-SQL commands into a txt file and reference the txt file as input to `SQLCMD`?

Comment: You might need to [Start SQL Server with Minimal Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-with-minimal-configuration)

Comment: @Legends [Please read before setting values that low](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options).

Comment: :D Ok, I got it to work via ` SQLCMD`. Had to try several times and also reboot once. Yes, I set it probably a way too low.